# Are there widely accepted names for 31edo modes?

Tags: scales, terminology, modes, microtonality

I am looking for scales and modes in 31edo, and I found this page:
https://en.xen.wiki/w/31edo_modes

It's overall a nice library of scales. The issue is, the namings are too unique that I cannot find any other source using them.

A few examples of names I am not sure about:
`Dylydian`, `Hemiolic Chromatic Dorian`, `Soft Diatonic Dorian`, `Intense Diatonic Phrygian/M.Dorian`, `Ratio 2:3 Chromatic Hypolydian`. etc.

I cannot find any info of these names that are not from the Xenharmonic Wiki itself, this is making me confused. Are these terms widely accepted in the microtonal community at all, or are they only used in this particular website and nothing beyond that? Do 31edo modes have widely accepted names at all (since the ordinary Dorian scale seems to also be called `Intense Diatonic Phrygian` in this wiki page)?

Comment: There’s a Xenharmonic facebook group that you might want to check out also.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the title.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Generally speaking, composers working within 31-EDO (and other microtonal systems) are either trying to parallel Tonal composition, in which case the diatonic names are sufficient, or they're composing music that doesn't concern itself with modes as theoretical building blocks.

Even within 12-EDO, there are many scales/modes that don't have common names. (Commonly) Named scales are more the exception than the rule.